# find a message from a curl request in apache logs

Tags: apache, http, post, curl

With a linux, I send a curl message like that:

`curl -X POST -d "hello" http:/server_adress`

the server is a Windows. I would like to find "hello" in my Apache log but I don't know how to do this.
Do you think the curl is correct ? 
What do I have to put in my php file to see "hello" in my apache log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer.

the message curl have to be like this:

`curl -X POST -d "message = hello" _http://server_adress`

and in the file php.

`$message=$_POST["message"];`

`write_debug_log("$message);`

It returns "hello" in the apache log

Answer (score 0):

Your curl command is okay. Its now you to the server log(and the administrator) to check the data on the log.

So far I know the data(means post data) doesn't come to by default in the log. You need to configure it from the log setting or something like that(if it is possible).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't know what to put in the file index.php to have "hello" in the log.

Comment: its in the `httpd.conf` file probably. configure there.

Comment: Ok, I will search there

Comment: I looked in the httpd.conf and I found nothing